# How to filter the list elements within list based on another list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list which contains a list as elements. Now i want to filter the elements of list based on another list when the list element consist more than 3 elements that is in another list within list. For more understanding lets say i have a list called `a`.

```
a = [(1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 25), (1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 29), (1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 31), (1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 36), (1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 41), (1, 5, 20, 22, 25, 29)]
```

Now i have another list which is `b`.

```
b = [(5,20,24,25,29,36),(1,22,25,29,31,41)]
```

What i want is i want to delete the sub-list i.e element of list `a` that consist more than 3 elements that is in sub-list `b`. Here `a[0]` consist of 4 elements that is in `b[0]` so i want to delete it. I do not want any sub list in list a that has more than 3 elements in either sub-list of `b`.
I am so confused, what shall i do?

Comment: @Austin: When you edit, make sure you just not only fixed the indent but also the variables and other minor things in the question text

Comment: How would you do this if you were doing it with pen and paper? The first thing to do is reason about the individual steps you would take mentally to do this task rather than just focusing on the whole.

Comment: @Bazingaa, Ok, done.

Comment: For each element of `a`, loop over the elements of `b` and count the number of shared elements.  Can there be duplicate items in the sublists?  How should those be counted?

Comment: Is this comparing if more 4 shared between both lists in b, to say it cant have 4 elements that match the the combined lists in b, or it cant match 4 in one or the other

Comment: Not in the combination, actually in each and every subelement in b separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is the brute force method. Assuming, as in your data, the items in each sublist are unique, you can use `set` with a list comprehension:

```
a_sets = list(map(set, a))
b_sets = list(map(set, b))

res = [sublist for idx, sublist in enumerate(a) if not \
       any(len(a_sets[idx] & b_set) > 3 for b_set in b_sets)]

[(1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 31), (1, 5, 20, 22, 24, 41)]
```

Comment: Are we comparing each list to the combined elements in b or just if it passes the test for each individual sublist in b

Comment: I read it as *any one* sublist of `b`, i.e. a test for each one. But looking back it's not completely clear. Taking OP's example, `Here a[0] consist of 4 elements that is in b[0]`, this seems to be the implication.

Comment: Yes a test for each one.